# Different characterisations of compact metric space: sequential compactness

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces, compactness

> Show that a sequentially compact space $X$ has property P.

> A metric space $X$ has property P, if for every open cover of $X$ there exists some $r > 0$ s.t. $B(x, r) \subseteq O$ for all $x \in X$.

**My attempt:**
Let $\mathcal{O} $ be an open cover of $X$ and suppose there didn't exist a Lebesgue number.
This means
\begin{equation}
  \left(\forall \epsilon = \frac{1}{n}\right)\; \exists x_{n}\in X\; \forall O \in \mathcal{O} 
  \colon B(x, \epsilon) \not \subseteq O
.\end{equation}
By assmuption, the in this way generated sequence $(x_{n})$ has a converging subsequence
$(x_{n_{k}})\to x^{*}$. We note that this subsequence is also a sequence which satisfies $(1)$, using $k$ instead
of $n$. However, this would mean that
\begin{align*}
\forall \epsilon > 0 \; \forall O \in \mathcal{O} \colon B(x^{*}, \epsilon)\not \subseteq O
\end{align*}
contradicting the fact that all $O$ are open.

I'm quite new to the topic and would like to know whether my attempt makes sense, or whether there is some mistake of thinking in there.

Comment: Your statement of the problem.and of the definition of a Lebesgue number for an open covering is imprecise. You need to fix that before you do the proof. The existence of a Lebesgue number is a property of the covering not the space.

Comment: I don’t see a problem in his definition, maybe this is how his course defines it. From the definition he states it should be possible for us to check the validity of his proof. I think it’s correct, but I would want someone with more reputation to verify this.